# How to start gnome wayland desktop from lightdm?

Tags: gnome, lightdm, gdm, display-manager, wayland

I installed Gnome 3.24 (`gnome-shell` and `gnome-desktop-environment`) on a previous Ubuntu 17.04 (Unity) installation.

I can start gnome Wayland session from display manager `gdm3`, but not from `Lightdm`. When trying to, I'm stuck on a non-interactive black screen with a blinking cursor.

I know that I could stick to `gdm3`, but there at least two reasons why I won't:

1. `Lightdm` is somehow much faster on boot
2. `gdm3` is not showing properly on dual monitor, like lightdm does (connection window and panel follows cursor on external monitor.

How can I start a `gnome 3.24`  `Wayland` session with Lightdm  as display manager ?

Comment: Exactly; for me gdm3 even won't start: systemd will just spin endlessly that some package is on Hold or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

A bug report has been filed and is currently being worked on. There are a few workarounds but it isn't a perfect fix. I was able to login using Wayland with this fix but I was not able to use logout.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1632772

One solution is to remove Unity 8 desktop:

```
sudo apt remove unity8-desktop-session
sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1632772/comments/23.

The login sessions LightDM lists are `.desktop` files stored in two places: `/usr/share/xsessions/` for X11 sessions; and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/`. Some of the files in those two directories will have the same filename. Remove the duplicates in `xsessions` for LightDM to launch those sessions in Wayland.

For example, I had `xsessions/gnome.desktop` and `wayland-sessions/gnome.desktop` and GNOME always launched under X11. I moved `xessions/gnome.desktop` to `gnome.desktop.disabled` and now GNOME uses Wayland.